# use python to run commands in batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I want to use python to run commands in a batch file. The screen capture below shows the batch file and commands in Windows cmd.
[image: screen capture]

I tried to use python to open the batch file.

```
import os
os.system('C:/Program Files/MetroCon-3.2/RepSend/RepSendQXGA64.bat')
```

This returns '1' which means failed.

```
import subprocess
filepath="C:/Program Files/MetroCon-3.2/RepSend/RepSendQXGA64.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print (p.returncode)
```

This return '0'. And the list of commands are in `stdout` and can be shown in python.

The question is how to run the specific command in the batch file as it runs in Windows cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run specific commands from the bat file, you could open the bat file as a txt file (Or use the stdout output), read it line by line and then communicate with the cmd via the winpexpect module.

```
import winpexpect
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
cmd = winpexpect.winspawn("cmd")
# Create read write buffers
cmd.logfile_read = read_buffer
cmd.logfile_write = write_buffer
cmd.sendline("insert whatever command line you want")
```

edit : If I understood you correctly, I could add the read/write buffer implemntation

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/Program Files/MetroCon-3.2/RepSend/")
os.startfile("RepSendQXGA64.bat")
```

or  this?

```
os.system("start /wait cmd /c RepSendQXGA64.bat")
```

Comment: I cannot use `os.system` to open this bat file. `subprocess` works.